# How to restrict length of file name to within maximum allowable?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

When I try to send an email to 30 recipients and a group of 60 recipients there is an error:

> Run-time error '-2147286788 (800300fc)

`Item.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG` is where the problem lies.

Within the code there is the comment `Sname` *might need restricting character length*.

I think the code is trying to make a file name from the subject of the email, the time and date, and the recipients email names, and there are too many characters in the file name.

The complete code is below. It is in the `ThisOutlookSession` module.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents SentItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Items = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
Set SentItems = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

Dim sPath As String
Dim dtDate As Date
Dim sName As String
Dim enviro As String

enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

sName = Item.Subject & "-" & Item.SenderName
ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"

dtDate = Item.ReceivedTime
sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"

sPath = enviro & "\Email\Inbox\"
Debug.Print sPath & sName
Item.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG

End If

End Sub

Private Sub SentItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

Dim sPath As String
Dim dtDate As Date
Dim sName As String
Dim enviro As String

enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

'Save name is the email subject plus who the email was sent to
sName = Item.Subject & "-" & Item.To 'might need restricting character length
ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"

dtDate = Item.ReceivedTime
sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"

sPath = enviro & "\Email\Sent Items\"
Debug.Print sPath & sName
Item.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG

End If

End Sub


Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
sChr As String _
)
sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Comment: So further research indicates that putting some kind of resume statement into the code will get me somewhere and enable the script to ignore the error. Providing this error is email specific and is only generated by emails with subject strings that exceed some mythical 250 plus character limit.

Comment: Do not ever use Resume next in this way. The code fails silently. Here you would think mail was saved but was not.

Answer (score 0):

Assume for simplicity a limit of 250 characters.

Reduce by length of the date:

```
Len(Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
  vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
  vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem))
```

Reduce by length of the path:

```
Len(enviro & "\Email\Sent Items\")
```

Say the two numbers above add to 100. 150 characters remain.

A simple fix would be:

```
'Save name is the email subject plus who the email was sent to
'sName = Item.Subject & "-" & Item.To
sName = left(Item.Subject, 50)  & "-" & left(Item.To, 99)
```

A more generic fix would include dynamically calculating the 50 and 99 based on the different length of enviro for other people.